# GroupByKey faster than CombineByKey

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have elements of kind *(Int, (Int, Int, Int)* in a *RDD*. The aim is to limit the elements with the same key to a certain threshold *t*. The simpler solution would be the following:

```
rdd.groupByKey().flatMapValues{iterable => {
  iterable.take(t)
}}
```

I thought it would be useful to replace this piece of code by *combineByKey*, to make use of the map-side aggregation throught the combiner, since there could be potentially more than *t* same keys in a single partition, leading to the following:

```
val function_createCombiner = (x: (Int, Int, Int)) => {
   ArrayBuffer[(Int, Int, Int)](x)
 }
val function_mergeValue = (accumulator: ArrayBuffer[(Int, Int, Int)],
                           x: (Int, Int, Int)) => {
  if(accumulator.size < t){
    accumulator += x
  }
  accumulator
}
val function_mergeCombiners = (accumulator1: ArrayBuffer[(Int, Int, Int)],
                               accumulator2: ArrayBuffer[(Int, Int, Int)]) => {
  val iter = accumulator2.iterator
  var saturated = false
  while(!saturated && iter.hasNext){
    if(accumulator1.length < t){
      accumulator1 += iter.next()
    } else {
      saturated = true
    }
  }
  accumulator1
}

rdd
.combineByKey(function_createCombiner, function_mergeValue, function_mergeCombiners)
.flatMapValues(x => x.toList)
```

Surprisingly, the *combineByKey* solution performs worse than the *groupByKey* solution. The GC works 50% of the time for the *combineByKey* solution, so i think i create to many temporary buffers. On the other hand, it is stated all over the internet, that groupByKey should be avoided by all means.

*CombineByKey* time: 11 minutes

*GroupByKey* time: 4,1 minutes

Do i have some terrible flaws in my *combineByKey* solution? Or do i miss something else?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: This question actually is a duplicate, i am sorry. This is due to the fact, that only a really small amount of elements appear more than t times. Therefore it is pretty obvious, that i (nearly) try to reimplement *groupByKey* by *combineByKey*. The only options are that i use *groupByKey*, which seems to be faster, or omit the step completely, if possible.
Anyways, thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you considered looking at the number of partitions in your RDD and comparing how many tasks are generated to complete the entire stage between these two approaches?

Comment: @AndrewMo the number of partitions are exactly equal for both approaches

Comment: I disagree with the duplicate tag. OP _does_ indeed reduce output when limiting to t elements...

Comment: One thing you could do to try and ease the GC load is presize your ArrayBuffers to the size `t`. (The defaut arrayBuffer size is 16, so if `t < 16`, you win because each new buffer will be smaller, you'll allocate less memory, and if `t > 16`, it could be even better because you would not have to resize (e.g. reallocate !) the buffers when their initial capacity overflows).

Comment: this is weird, I agree that combineByKey should be much faster. How much times did you run the test? Can you confirm the results are the same for combineByKey and groupByKey (same number of values for each key (obviously there is no guarantee that each key will have the same values))? As a test can you partition the data before using groupByKey/combineByKey and confirm that combineByKey is quicker (it should be based on your code)?

Comment: thanks for the input, presizing the array buffers is a good idea, i will implement it.

@SiLaf i think the amount of values per key is identical, i will test it. What does the test of prepartitioning the data achieve?

Comment: Honestly it was just clutching at straws. If the data is partitioned beforehand then your mergeCombiner code will never be run. Partition the data and cache. Run groupByKey().flatMapValues() on the cached data, followed by combineByKey().flatMapValues() on the cached data. Then finish the job. Do this as part of the same job to be sure they are using the same inputs. Time how long each took using the GUI. If combineByKey() now out-performs groupByKey() then maybe there is a problem with your mergeCombiner code. As I said; 'clutching at straws'

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would go with the `reduceByKey` when working with `rdds`:)

```
rdd
 .mapValues(List(_))
 .reduceByKey((v1, v2) => (v1++v2).take(t))
 .flatMapValues(identity(_))
```

I find it to be much easier than `combineByKey` and it's *usually* much more efficient than `groupByKey` because it does map side reduce before shuffling data around. I say *usually* because there are situations (when you gather all values per key, for instance) where `groupByKey` performs as well as `reduceByKey`.

Comment: but with this solution you create one List per element, where as with the combineByKey solution (which does map-side aggregation too), you only create one list per element per partition (i hope this is understandable).
Also, you concatenate v1 and v2 and afterwards prune it, is this performance-wise equal to my solution?

Comment: I tested your solution, it takes significantly longer than the groupByKey approach, with around 45% GC time for each task.

Comment: I find this curious. Can you share some information about your dataset? How big is your `rdd` (how many rows) and roughly how many values have the same key and what is your t set to?

Comment: Also, which version of Spark are you using?

Comment: I am using Spark 2.1.0.
I am not quite sure how many elements share the same key, i will find this out. I use t=254. Since the amount of data is reduced by a fair amount, i would say that there are many keys which have more than t values in my case. Again, i will deliver exact numbers.

Comment: So the dataset is about 36 gb in size. Unfortunetalely only around 10 mb of elements met the requirement, that t > 254 ... I think i really evaluated my data wrong. It would probably be better to take measurements to completely omit this task in the job if possible.